# Potentially Useful Question

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been solving problems using a "Potentially Helpful Formulas" sheet from my esteemed math professor. i want to solve for:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4} =$ ?

On my formula sheet i have:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

Which looks similar to what i want, but not quite. Might someone guide me towards the solution (or provide the solution with explanation?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^z} = \zeta(z)$ where $\zeta$ is the Rieman-Zeta function. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/nice-proofs-of-zeta4-pi4-90

Comment: You can use [Parseval's  theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304959/using-parseval-s-theorem-to-evaluate-a-sum) to evaluate the sum.

Comment: Maybe the question is potentially useful. Its title is most certainly not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a sketch of one of many possible proofs.

**Step1.** Prove that over the interval $[0,2\pi]$, the function:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$$
is a second degree-polynomial whose graphics passes through the points:
$$(0,\pi^2/6),\quad (\pi,-\pi^2/12),\quad (2\pi,\pi^2/6).$$

**Step2.** Deduce from Lagrange interpolation that:
$$ f(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{x(2\pi-x)}{4}.$$

**Step3.** Apply Parseval's identity to $f(x)$:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)^2\,dx = \pi\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}.$$

**Step4.** Prove, through the second step, that:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)^2\, dx = \frac{\pi^5}{90}.$$

**Conclusion:**

> $$\zeta(4)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}.$$